# How do I delete a SKSpriteNode?

Tags: swift2, xcode7

I have figured out how to create a SKSpriteNode when you touch the screen using the touchesBegan method or the touchesMoves method in Xcode. What I what to figure out now is how do I delete that one node that I just created when I lift my finger off the screen.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please share the code.

Comment: I've tried adding addChild(SKSpriteNode) to the method touchesBegan and then removeFromParent(SKSpriteNode) in touchesEnded but it does not work. I don't have any code right now because I am still trying to figure it out. I would like it to appear when I touch the screen and then be able to be moved around with my finger and the something happen when I take my finger off.

Answer (score 0):

touchesBegan and touchesEnded are methods of your SKScene that get called asynchronously.  You must hold the sprite object you create in touchesBegan in a variable belonging to the SKScene so that you can still access it when touchesEnded is called.

If you already have done that, removeFromParent should work, but why not just set it to hidden and reuse the same sprite next time the user touches the screen.